# Update the value of my defaultValue on my TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

This is my `handleUpdate` function. The `handleUpdate` is working when I try to add a sample data on my `useState('sample')`, but if I try to add it using `TextInput` it only saves a `null` even though I added a data on `TextInput`. The `route.params.user.firstname` is the `defaultValue` of my `firstname` that I passed from my drawer. Did I added correctly the `defaultValue` or do I need to add `value`property on my `TextInput`.

```
const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState('');
const id = route.params.user._id;

const handleUpdate = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch(USER_API + `${id}`, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'firstname': firstname
        })
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Success:', result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
};
```

The `TextInput`

```
<View style={styles.viewContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Edit info</Text>
    <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
            style={styles.inputText}
            placeholder="First Name"
            placeholderTextColor="#003f5c"
            defaultValue={route.params.user.firstname}
            onChangeText={(text) => setFirstname({ text })}
        />
    </View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginBtn} onPress={() => handleUpdate()}>
        <Text style={styles.loginTextBtn}>SAVE</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Error message from my api when I added a data on my `TextInput`.

```
{message: "Cast to string failed for value "{ text: 'John' }" at path "firstname""}message: "Cast to string failed for value "{ text: 'Dexter' }" at path "firstname""__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the datatype of `firstname` from a string to an object with key `text`.

Remove the object notation and pass it the string:

```js
setFirstname({ text })
```

to

```js
setFirstname(text)
```

You also aren't giving the `TextInput` a `value`. The `defaultValue` only gets used one time, any updates to it will not be reflected. Set its value with `value={firstname}`

Comment: It worked! By the way how can I update the parent component when the `firstname` is being updated without refreshing the app?

Comment: You'd have to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to get it to re-render the parent. A component only rerenders if it's state has changed or if it is a child of a component whose state has changed. In order to get the parent to re-render, you will need to change its state.

Comment: Is there a good sample of lifting the state up on `ReactNative`?

Comment: Probably but I don't have any recommendations. It should be the exact same concept though.